# How do I disable right-click menu in APP-mode in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, citrix

I'm setting up a new application in Citrix, it points to a CMD file that will open a specific webpage:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="http://..." -no-default-browser-check

So far so good, but i wish to restrict any user to right click on the top of the webpage to access the context(?) menu. Or more specific, Open browser window (Ctrl+T). I do not want the users to start a new browser window.

Kiosk mode isn't an option since it's fullscreen.

Is FireFox a better solution, if so, how?